# Css Modification of a template in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have found a nice template to use for my shopping cart page [Reference Template Link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-shopping-cart)

I'm basically modifying it so that the top portion(Product,Price,Quantity,Subtotal) headings only appear once and the middle part where the data resides is repeated multiple times and the button part is also rendered once.

I have tried to do it in this fashion but due to this, my `CSS` gets messed up which i have been unable to correct myself.

Here is a screenshot of my current modified shopping cart page.[image: Shopping Cart Page]

The alignment is off as you can see.I need to correct this.

This is the relevant code for the same.

```
view_cart.js


import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import './view_cart.css'
import {ToastContainer, toast,style} from 'react-toastify'

var hiding='';
class View_cart extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={item_list:{},"total_items_price":'',product_count:''}
    this.view_cart_details=this.view_cart_details.bind(this)
    this.delete_item_cart=this.delete_item_cart.bind(this)
    this.product_state=this.product_state.bind(this)
    this.update_per_item_details=this.update_per_item_details.bind(this)
  }

  registeration_notification(value_to_render)
  {
    toast(value_to_render,
      {
        //position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        autoClose: 3000,
      }
    );
  }

  product_state(e,product_name,manufacturer)
  {
    this.setState({"product_count":e.target.value})
    console.log(this.state.product_count)
    //console.log(product_name,manufacturer)
    this.update_per_item_details(product_name,manufacturer)
  }

  update_per_item_details(product_name,manufacturer)
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_item_cart/',
    {
      method:"PUT",
      headers:
      {
      'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
      body:JSON.stringify({"product_name":product_name,"manufacturer":manufacturer,quantity:this.state.product_count})
  })
  .then(something =>something.json())
  .then(findResponse =>
    {
      console.log(findResponse,typeof(findResponse))
      if((Object.keys(findResponse).length)===1 && (Object.keys(findResponse).includes("message")))
      {
        //hiding='displayNone';
        //console.log(hiding)
        //console.log("A user with this name already exists.")
        this.registeration_notification("The Quantity and the amount have been changed.")
        this.view_cart_details()
      }
    }
  )
  }

  display_cart()
  {
    //console.log(Object.keys(this.state.item_list))
    const mapping = Object.keys(this.state.item_list).map((item,id) =>
    {
      console.log(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path'])
      var location = require('./Images/'.concat(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path']))
      //console.log(location)
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <table id="cart" className="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-th="Product">
                  <div className="row" style={{width:1000}}>
                    <div className="col-sm-1 hidden-xs"><img src={location} alt="..." className="img-responsive"/></div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                      <h4 className="nomargin">{this.state.item_list[item]["Name"]} {'by '.concat(this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Price">{this.state.item_list[item]["original_price"]}</td>
                <td data-th="Quantity">
                  <select onClick={(e) => this.product_state(e,this.state.item_list[item]['Name'],this.state.item_list[item]['manufacturer'])}>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" className="text-center">{this.state.item_list[item]['price']}</td>
                <td className="actions" data-th="">
                  <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={() =>this.delete_item_cart(this.state.item_list[item]['Name'],this.state.item_list[item]['manufacturer'])}><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
          )
    })
  return mapping
}

  sample_cookie_output()
  {
    const test_cookie_testing = new Cookies();

    var auth_string='Token '
    console.log((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization'))),typeof((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))))
    return (auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))
  }

  delete_item_cart(product_name_delete,manufacturer_name)
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_item_cart/',
    {
      method:"POST",
      headers:
      {
      'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
      body:JSON.stringify({"product_name":product_name_delete,"manufacturer":manufacturer_name})

  })
  .then(something =>something.json())
  .then(findResponse =>
    {
      console.log(findResponse,typeof(findResponse))
      if((Object.keys(findResponse).length)===1 && (Object.keys(findResponse).includes("Data Deletion")))
      {
        hiding='displayNone';
        console.log(hiding)
        //console.log("A user with this name already exists.")
        this.registeration_notification("The Product has been removed from the cart")


      }
    }
  )
  }

  view_cart_details()
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_cart/',
    {
      method:"GET",
      headers:
      {
        'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
  })
.then(something =>something.json())
.then(findResponse =>
  {
    console.log(findResponse)
    this.setState({"item_list":findResponse[0],"total_items_price":findResponse[1]})
  }

)
  }

componentDidMount(){
  this.view_cart_details()
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <App/>
      <div>
        <table id="cart" className="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={{width:"50%"}}>Product</th>
              <th style={{width:"10%"}}>Price</th>
              <th style={{width:"8%"}} className="text-center">Quantity</th>
              <th style={{width:"22%"}} className="text-center">Subtotal</th>
              <th style={{width:"10%"}}></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {this.display_cart()}
          <tfoot>
            <tr className="visible-xs">
              <td className="text-center"><strong>Total {this.state.total_items_price}</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="/display/" className="btn btn-warning"><i className="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a></td>
              <td colSpan="1" className="hidden-xs"></td>
              <td><a href="/checkout" className="btn btn-success">Checkout<i className ="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
              <td className="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>{this.state.total_items_price}</strong></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        <ToastContainer/>
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
}

export default View_cart




    view_cart.css

.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    table#cart tbody td .form-control{
        width:20%;
        display: inline !important;
    }
    .actions .btn{
        width:36%;
        margin:1.5em 0;
    }

    .actions .btn-info{
        float:left;
    }
    .actions .btn-danger{
        float:right;
    }

    table#cart thead { display: none; }
    table#cart tbody td { display: block; padding: .6rem; min-width:320px;}
    table#cart tbody tr td:first-child { background: #333; color: #fff; }
    table#cart tbody td:before {
        content: attr(data-th); font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block; width: 8rem;
    }

    table#cart tfoot td{display:block; }
    table#cart tfoot td .btn{display:block;}
}
```

On a Side note-How do i learn how to modify the `CSS` styles properly myself?

Comment: You can start with `CSS` here https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Solved this question by using  and by removing the top table tags in the display_cart function.